# Not a managed type importing entity

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a maven multi module project.
It is composed by two spring boot 3 application and one common library, sharing dtos.
Both spring boot application works just fine. What I'm trying to do is to use a repository and an entity of one spring boot application to the other, maybe is not possible.
So I have this app1 that should scan entity and repository also for the app2:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages={"com.acme.app1.entity","com.acme.app2.entity"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"com.acme.app1.repository","com.acme.app2.repository"})

public class App1 {...}
```

The app2 entity and repository is like that:

```
package com.acme.app2.entity;

@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(indexes = {...})
public class Home  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.VARCHAR)
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(36)", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;
    ....
```

And the repository:

```
package com.acme.app2.repository;

@Repository
public interface HomeRepository extends JpaRepository<Home, UUID> {...}
```

So I thought that App1 could see the entity and repository of App2, but when I try to use it in a service like this:

```
package com.acme.app1.service;

import com.acme.app2.repository.HomeRepository;

@Service
public class DefaultApp1Service extends Throwable implements App1Service {

 
    @Autowired
    private  HomeRepository homeRepository;
```

First IntelliJ tells me that homeRepository could not be wired, no beans of HomeRepository type found, and when I run the application I got

> Not a managed type: class com.acme.app2.entity.Stock

Answer (score 2):

I created an example to test the importing of repositories/entities from another maven module: https://github.com/Lefeverw/stackoverflow-importing-entity

It's true that the IDE does give a warning message that the `homeRepository` could not be autowired. However, the code does compile and runs successfully. In my opinion it's probably a limitation of the IDE (maybe it doesn't handle the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation correctly).

On the error message `Not a managed type: class com.acme.app2.entity.Stock`. I suspect there's something else wrong here, but it's impossible to figure out what exactly without more information. Could you share a bit more code or upload a minimal, reproducible example to GitHub?

In any case, you are free to use the example and compare to your current code. Good luck!

Comment: thank you very much for the effort of making a workable example. Both the application are SpringBoot, I changed your code and still works, but mine not, it seems it is no able to look into the other entity. I'll try to shrink my app to narrow down the problem, thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I found out which is the problem. In the app1 I have configured the database connection with two database one for read and one for write, and for some reason this blocks the entity scanning. I roll back to one database connection for both read and write and now it works fine!